# Magento 1.9.x - How can rewrite Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien class

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, abstract-class

I am trying to re-write Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien class in my custom module but getting error :

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Block_Messages::addMessages() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection
```

What I have tried -

**config.xml**

```
<core>
      <rewrite>
           <session>Test_HelloDeveloper_Model_Product</session>
       </rewrite>
</core>
```

**And ...Model/Product.php**

```
class Test_HelloDeveloper_Model_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien {

    public function start($sessionName=null)
    {
        Mage::log('method overrided...', null, 'override.log');

    } 
}
```

What can be issues?

Comment: The error you have referenced is regarding the parameter you have passed to `addMessages` method.

Comment: After removing the parameter, facing the same issue. But when I print It's throwing different error - Fatal error: Call to a member function getItems() on null in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php on line 115

Comment: that means the collection of message is null